# How to pass db path name in new SQLiteConnection in UWP?

Tags: sqlite, uwp

I am working with Sqlite db in uwp, I am able to create db successfully without any issue in Local folder of my app.

But when I try to create in other places, I get error as

```
"SQLite.Net.SQLiteException: 'Could not open database file: E:\Users\PC3\Pictures\Abcd\MyDbFolder\mydb.sqlite (CannotOpen)"
```

I got the path string using StorageFolder.Path which I got through Folder picker, then I added it to FutureAccessList too. Though not works. Since the New db connection method expects the path, I am struggling for a long time, to use path in the Constructor.

```
//DbPathFromFAList = foldername.path (got from FutureAccess List) + mydbName.sqlite;
sqliteConn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DbPathFromFAList);
```

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations) MSDN article for more details on accessing files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rob said in this [thread](https://apac01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsocial.msdn.microsoft.com%2FForums%2Fsqlserver%2Fen-US%2F5926b643-d777-42c1-99e4-3968177cd205%2Fuwp-sqlite-database-access-when-the-file-is-in-documents-area-%3Fforum%3Dwpdevelop&data=02%7C01%7C%7C2da5201379ad49ed3a8b08d643c90d86%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C636770928121956025&sdata=RvIm4%2F2c%2FBGFbrbSmsY5440cCWYMW0vGXismBvVfhv8%3D&reserved=0),

> SQLite uses paths not streams and bypasses the file broker. It's database has to be in application data so the app has direct read/write permissions or install dir for read only.

You could not pass the path string parameter such as `D:` `E:` to `SQLiteConnection` method, even though you have used `FilePicker` to get the full file's permission.

In general, we use [`LocalFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_LocalFolder) to store db file that could access directly.

```
DbFilePath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Sqlite.db");
sqliteConn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DbFilePath);
```

And the specified path is located at:

```
C:\Users[Your User Name]\AppData\Local\Packages[Your Package Name]\LocalState
```

You can not set it to the `D` or `E` disk. If you have used external database, please copy the db file to the local folder. for more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.copyasync#Windows_Storage_StorageFile_CopyAsync_Windows_Storage_IStorageFolder_).